# How do I force download with html/javascript in a jsp from IE 9 and above?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, internet-explorer, jstl

I have a link to an img

```
<a href="relative_Path_of_IMG">Save</a>
```

and i need that this link make direct download of this file. 
On Chrome and Firefox works fine with the attribute 'download'

```
<a href="relative_Path_of_IMG" download>Save</a>
```

but on ie this doesnt works fine. 
I have found on internet the JS comand window.document.execCommand and i try to use on this way

```
window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
```

but this way open a window to the user chose a folder to save, and i need that the download execute automaticaly on the default folder of downloads of the user, like attribute download works on Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks

Paulo Filipe

Comment: So force it from the serverside with the correct headers.

Comment: What is the `Content-Disposition` header being sent with the file?  That header is used to tell the browser what to do with the downloaded content.  (Of course, the browser can still be configured to ignore it and perform some other action.  You can't control that from the server.)

Comment: I have that the user click on the link 'save' and only start the download, with no windows asking the folder and no reload of the page

Comment: to change the headers i ( i think) have to redirect to another page with only img in this page with the correctly headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a JSP and use it as a servlet. It'll recieve a link by parameter with the url of image that you want download.

This servlet will open a stream to read the file and other stream to write the output on your browser. With this your browser will be responsable to handling your file.

Follow a example of this JSP.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

```java
<%
String urlPrefix = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort();

String fileUrl = request.getParameter("fileUrl");
if (fileUrl == null || "".equals(fileUrl.trim())) {
    throw new Exception("No image Found.");
}

String fileName = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8"));

String fullEncodedUrl = urlPrefix + URIUtil.encodePath(fileUrl);

URL url = new URL(fullEncodedUrl);

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

BufferedOutputStream outs = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
int len;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
while ((len = stream.read(buf)) > 0) {
    outs.write(buf, 0, len);
}
outs.close();
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The user should get a choice of where to save files. Its only fair, since the download is going onto their machine.

In Chrome and Firefox there is a choice in settings that (in Firefox) defaults to always saving the files to the Downloads folder.   The user chose to always save to the same folder by not changing that setting. They could just as easily change to the next setting saying "Always ask me where to save files."  But THEY choose, not the website. If Microsoft had a similar option the user could choose it, but you (i.e. any server-side code) cannot.